# jQuery accordion, on trigger click throws an error! : object is not a function

Tags: jquery, html

Ok an have an accordion, but i am not using jQuery UI. This is my code

xHTML:

```
<ul>
    <h2>What are your hours?</h2>
    <li>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim tesque felis.</li>

    <h2>What are your hours?</h2>
    <li>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim tesque felis.</li>

    <h2>What are your hours?</h2>
    <li>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim tesque felis.</li>

    <h2>What are your hours?</h2>
    <li>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim tesque felis.</li>
</ul>
```

And jquery:

```
$.fn.acc = function() {

  $('li').not(':first').hide();
  $('h2:first').addClass('selected'); 
    $('h2').on('click', function() {
      $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      var li = $(this).next('li');
      check = (li.is(':visible')) ? li.slideUp(200) : ($('li').slideUp(200))(li.slideDown(250));
  });
};
// Call the function here
$(function() {
  $('ul').acc();
});
```

The code is working, but when you click on h2 tag every time you get in the console log the following message:

Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function.

Can someone tell me what is the problem, because the code is ok and works like a charm.

Here is a [**[link][1](http://jsfiddle.net/msxps/tKru3/2/)**](http://jsfiddle.net/msxps/tKru3/2/)
Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QUPqH/ - works fine for me. Are you sure you're referencing jQuery properly?

Comment: You can't put an h2 inside of a ul. The only direct descendant of a <ul> tag is an <li> tag.. below the li you can have any tag that is allowed in the body of your document.

Comment: I know that the direct descendant of ul is li. Thanls for the reminder.

This is how i refer to jQuery

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

The error in Mozilla is: $("li").slideUp(200) is not a function

In Chrome is : Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I answered and it works without error.. Try this url:  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code redone much simpler and with valid html
-- Updated to use selected class -- 
http://jsfiddle.net/5HfBc/6/

html:

```
<ul>
    <li><h2>What are your hours?</h2>
        <p>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim tesque felis.</p>
     </li>
     <li><h2>What are your hours?</h2>
        <p>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim tesque felis.</p>
     </li>
     <li><h2>What are your hours?</h2>
        <p>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim tesque felis.</p>
        </li>


    </ul>
```

javascript:

```
$.fn.acc = function() {
    $('li:first p').addClass("selected").show();
    $('li h2').click(function(e) {           
        $(this).siblings("p").slideToggle(200)
            .parent().addClass("selected")
            .siblings("li").removeClass("selected")
            .find("p").slideUp(200);
    });
};

$(function() {
  $('ul').acc();
});
```

css:

```
ul{width:400px; margin:auto; }
li {margin: 0px; padding: 0;  text-align: left;} 
li p { display: none; }

h2 { font-size:12px; padding:0.5em; background: #e4e4e4; margin: 0px; cursor: pointer; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.5em; line-height: 2em;  border-bottom: 1px solid #c5c5c5; border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #cdcdcd;} 
.selected h2 {background: #dcdcdc; color:black;}
h2:hover {background-color:#dcdcdc;}
```

Comment: Ok now if you click the open one it will close it! Just change slideDown to slideToggle (as shown now).

Comment: Note that on here if you get an answer that works for you then you should mark as accepted (and typically upvote it as well!)

Answer (score 0):

On your line starting with `check =`, try replacing `li` with `$(li)` - still referring to the variable (as opposed to `$('li')`, but making jQuery go find it.